# rank in a partitioned regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

Let us consider a regression model

$ y = X_1 \beta_1 + X_2 \beta_2 + u $

where $y$ is $n \times 1$, $X_1$ is $n \times p_1$, $X_2$ is $n \times p_2$. Assume that $rank(X_1)=p_1$ and $rank(X_2)=r_2 \le p_2$.

By multiplying $M_1 = I_n - X_1(X_1'X_1)^{-1} X_1'$ to the above model, we have

$ M_1y = M_1 X_2 \beta_2 + M_1 u $

I don't know how to obtain $rank(M_1 X_2)$. If $M_1$ were positive definite, we have $rank(M_1 X_2)=rank(X_2)$. However, unfortunately, $M_1$ is positive semidefinite.
I'm wondering under what condition $rank(M_1 X_2)=rank(X_2)$ holds?

I have checked many textbooks, but this is not discussed at all even for the full rank case with $rank(X_2)= p_2$.

Any comments would be appreciated!